# Should you use the private access modifier if it's redundant?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Given that these two examples are equivalent, which do you think is preferrable?

**Without explicit modifier**

```
public class MyClass
{

    string name = "james";

    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    void SomeMethod() { ... }

}
```

**With explicit modifier**

```
public class MyClass
{

    private string name = "james";

    public string Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private void SomeMethod() { ... }

}
```

---

I've always used the latter, but recently I've started adopting the former style.  The private is redundant as that's the default accessor modifier, so doesn't it make sense to exclude it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think explicity stating private helps in readability. It won't allow for a programmer to  interpret its visibility differently.

Comment: It's pretty clear in the C# spec that the default modifier for classes is private.  It's also a commonly asked question in interviews.

Comment: So true.. the compiler will remove it anyway. And those few letters don't cost a thing!

Comment: It's extremely helpful if you have developers on the team that are learning C# after years of programming with Java. Even though I know better, my instinct is to default to Java defaults.

Comment: how long does it take to type pri and hit space in VS? I mean .. we're talking milliseconds here ;) .. Readability > all

Comment: @jonnii. ya the spec states that, but as James said, in java the default is protected, so newer programmers coming from java may not know. or just newer programmers in general for that matter.

Comment: Never mind newer programmers -- explicit is almost always better. Don't make me think. :) +1 to this answer.

Comment: The default access modifier in Java is 'default', not 'protected'.  Although 'default' may be similar to protected or private, I'm pretty sure there is a subtle difference.

Comment: Also, after a quick google search, it appears that the default access modifier for C# is 'internal' and not 'private'.

Comment: @Dalin: It's private for members of types (including nested types) and internal for top-level types.

Comment: StyleCop enforces you to always explicitly state the visibility. Just getting in the habit has helped prevent me from leaving off the visibility on public members by accident.

Comment: The default access modifier in Java is actually "package-private". The member appears as public to other classes in the same package, but as private to other packages and to subclasses. More details here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @Will Eddins, the very fact that you could leave off the visibility "by accident" shows that the members didn't need to be public.  If they did, you would have already used them in a context that required them to be public.  This is why it's best to omit the visibility, so that things aren't visible until they *need* to be.

Comment: This is an old thread, but still a discussed matter. Well in case someone noticed this, I personally don't take sides about this subject. In the end, you're coding for a team/company. And each team is different. You gotta discuss these things with the team, not the community

Answer (score 56):

It looks that we are the only one, but personally, **I support** the let's remove private campaign.

My concern is that public and private are so similar, 6-7 chars length, blue, starting with 'p', so it's much harder to point a public method between 10 explicit private ones than between 10 that have no access attribute.

Also, it's an advantage since lazy people in your team tend to save writing the modifier and making the method private, which is actually a good thing. Otherwise you end up with everything public.

I usually prefer explicit over implicit, but that's more important in language corner cases (tricky cheats) that in a widespread feature. Here I think long-rung maintainability is more important.

Also, I usually like when code is simple and clear in a *mathematical* way over when the code is explicit in order to preserve future coder's ignorance. That's the VB way, not C#...

Comment: We should start a support group!

Comment: have your editor colour them differently if you don't like them both blue

Comment: Not all editors can color different modifiers different colors.  Some add-ins (like CodeRush) can display different symbols for them, though.

Comment: I'm in the same camp, although I don't mind if private is used. My primary reason is that C# code lines are usually very long (the leading indent space, long type names, etc.). Removing the private makes it shorter. And a block of private members kinda looks as terse as the traditional C program.

Comment: Shorter is more elegant. Folk who need explicit clutter like 'private', extra brackets and unnecessary operators should learn the language.

Comment: Agreed.  For me 'private' modifiers increase 'noise-to-signal' ratio when browsing the code.

Comment: +1  I always like to write as little as possible so anything that is not necessary I will omit. I think it improves readability by making it less cluttered and allowing more code to show on the screen.

Comment: True, because they are access *modifier*. Why add a modifier when it is not actually *modified*?

Answer (score 27):

I always omit it for two reasons: to reduce visual clutter, and to do the right thing by default.

In C#, everything defaults to the **least visibility possible**.  A class member (field, method, property) defaults to private.  A class defaults to internal.  A nested class defaults to private.

Thus if you omit your visibility except where you need it, you'll be automatically using the least visibility possible, which is the right way to do things anyway.

If you need something to be **more** visible, then add the modifier.  This makes it easy to see items that deviate from the default visibility.

(Unfortunately, this rule only holds for C#.  In VB .NET and in F#, the defaults are quite different and definitely not "least visibility possible" in most cases.)

Comment: While I do think the idea of being as explicit as possible is good, in this case, it's either public or private so having public in front of declarations IS being explicit. This is technically not right because there are different modifiers but for all intents and purposes it is. It's really a fault of the language not to enforce either style.

Answer (score 25):

Marking it as private makes it clear that it is deliberate, rather than "I didn't actually think about it, so I don't know if it would be better as something else."; so I do like making it explicit. I wouldn't get religious about it, though.

Also - this prevents having to remember rules... members are private by default, (outer) types are internal by default; nested types are private by default...

Make it clear... make it explicit ;-p

Comment: But the rules are easy to remember.  You could restate them as "Everything is as little visible as possible".  Or "Everything is private unless it can't be" (outer types can't be because then nothing could use them).  There's nothing hard about remembering the defaults.

Comment: If it being private by default, because you left off the modifier and didn't spend time thinking about it, has no negative impact on behavior, would actually spending time thinking about it have yielded a different result? Also, one already has to remember the difference between public and private (and any other modifiers in-between). Remembering that everything defaults to least visible/accessible seems like it's part of understanding what those modifiers mean.

Answer (score 10):

I've been developing full-time in C# for about 7 years now, and until I read this topic I didn't know what the default access modifier is.  I knew that one existed, but I've never, ever used it.

I like explicitly declaring my intent as I code.  Both because the declarations are there for me to see when I go back and look at it, and because actually thinking and typing the word "private" when I write a method makes me think just a little more about what I have it in mind to do.

Comment: "I've been developing full-time in C# for about 7 years now, and until I read this topic I didn't know what the default access modifier is." --> That takes some guts to admit :)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I prefer the private modifier - I like explicitness. For fields, it also highlights that it's a member variable as opposed to a function variable (the only difference otherwise is location - which is okay if folks can indent properly, but can be confusing otherwise).

Answer (score 5):

I always prefer to be explicit, even if it is redundant. This provides built-in code comments and can be helpful for the next guy, especially if he's a noob. :-)

Comment: I like this argument. Let me use parenthesis galore around all my math notations because the next guy might not know math (even tho he's a programmer). People treat this like declaration visibility is like the holy grail of programming knowledge. Also, make sure to never use var, the noob might not know what it is, better write the type 20 times. One could even argue that "the noob" might understand the code better if there's no "private" keyword to confuse him.

Answer (score 5):

I like to be super-explicit usually. I will go for specifying "private" always. However there is another reason : Programmers coming from programming languages where the default visibility is **NOT** private but public, for example PHP.

Comment: Yeah, end up, they(PHP programmers) will create a bunch of private members which what they really want is public modifier and the implemented class is not tested from outside class.

Comment: Do you also always seal your classes I hope? :)

Comment: But is that really an actual problem? Because they'll notice quickly they can't call the members and everything except the required bits being private is good so there's no harm. Truly switching to a different language and it's common style is so much more than learning the default visibility...

Answer (score 3):

Always use the explicit form.  If for whatever reason the underlying assumption changes, the code with an explicit denotation of access won't break, whereas the implicit connotation my easily break.

Also, when you are talking about different types of structures, they may have different default accessibilities.  Without the explicit modifiers, the ownus is on the reader to know which structure has what default.  E.g. in C#, struct fields default to `public`, class fields default to `private`, and class definitions default to `internal`.

Comment: Changing this rule after 22 years will not happen. The default is least visibility, really not much to remember or think about. It's visual clutter and apparently we need what-ifs and lets-assume-the-rules-are-complicated to justify it.

Answer (score 3):

I go for explicit all the time.  If nothing else it demonstrates your intention more clearly.  If I want something to be private I will say so.  Explicitly typing the modifier makes sure I think about it, rather than just leaving things private because its quicker.  That an a long list of members line up better :)

Answer (score 2):

I always specify the visibility explicitly.  I prefer not letting the compiler guess my intentions.

Comment: "guess" really is the wrong word here. The rule is least visibility by default except otherwise specified. It's like using your indicator lights on every corner, even when not required and nobody else is there.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct but since you want your code to be understandable for everyone i think you should include, you never know when if someone does not know this

Answer (score 1):

First I will ask if there is a previous code convention/standard about that being used by the team. If there is any, you should follow it.

If you have to define the convention, I will push for the explicit way.

My reasons?;

- I like to keep the same structure (I mean a.-access modifier, b.-return-type/type, c.-name).
- I don't want (and I don't expect others) to remember all the modifiers by default ([which are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#member-access)).
- Not all the languages have the same rules.
- And somehow I think that, somehow, forces the developer to think and be more conscious about the scope of the variable/method and the exposition of those. If you have some experience this will probably not apply, but if you are a newbie, or you work with people with less experience, I think that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding has always been members have "internal" accessibility unless stated otherwise.  If that's true, the "private" modifier would be required to ensure those members are in fact private.

Regardless of whether I'm correct about the above or not, leaving the modifier in place will increase the readability of the code in case another developer is later modifying this class and is curious about the accessibility.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Members are "private" unless stated otherwise. *Types* (or at least, outer-types) are internal by default; and different again for nested classes. See - there are already 3 scenarios to remember - worth making it explicit ;-p

Comment: You don't have to remember three scenarios.  All you have to remember is that by default everything has the least visibility it can possibly have.  An outer type can't be private; if it were, nothing could access it.  An inner type *can* be private, since it can be accessed by its outer type, and that's why private is its default visibility.  The default visibilities in C# are perfectly logical - and thus it's *not* worth making it explicit.

Comment: Members have internal (`Friend`) visibility by default in VB .NET.  The VB .NET rules basically require you to make visibility explicit, because there's no apparent logic to them.  The C# rules have one simple logical rule (see previous comment), and it's safe to leave the defaults unless you need to change them.