# Structures in C#

Tags: c#, struct

I am using a structure in my program as below:

```
public struct chromo_typ
{
        public string   bits;  
        public float    fitness;

        chromo_typ(string bts, float ftns)
        {
            bits = bts;
            fitness = ftns;
        }
};
```

I am using the constructor defined in the struct i.e. chromo_typ(string bts, float ftns) in my main(). My main() contains the following code:

```
chromo_typ[] temp = new chromo_typ[VM_Placement.AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];

                    chromo_typ ct = new chromo_typ();

                    int cPop = 0;

                    //loop until we have created POP_SIZE new chromosomes
                    while (cPop < VM_Placement.AlgorithmParameters.pop_size)
                    {
                        // we are going to create the new population by grabbing members of the old population
                        // two at a time via roulette wheel selection.
                        string offspring1 = p.Roulette(TotalFitness, Population);
                        string offspring2 = p.Roulette(TotalFitness, Population);

                        //add crossover dependent on the crossover rate
                        p.Crossover(offspring1, offspring2);

                        //now mutate dependent on the mutation rate
                        p.Mutate(offspring1);
                        p.Mutate(offspring2);

                        //add these offspring to the new population. (assigning zero as their
                        //fitness scores)
                        temp[cPop++] = ct.chromo_typ(offspring1, 0.0f);
                        temp[cPop++] = ct.chromo_typ(offspring2, 0.0f);

                    }//end loop
```

I am getting the following error at `temp[cPop++] = ct.chromo_typ(offspring1, 0.0f);` and `temp[cPop++] = ct.chromo_typ(offspring2, 0.0f);`

> Error: `'VM_Placement.Program.chromo_typ' does not contain a
>   definition for 'chromo_typ' and no extension method 'chromo_typ'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'VM_Placement.Program.chromo_typ'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)`

Am I using structure incorrectly? How can I resolve this?

Comment: You forgot to use the *new* keyword.  A constructor is not a method.

Comment: Did you mean `temp[cPop++] = new chromo_typ(offspring1, 0.0f);` ?

Comment: Tried using 'new' keyword i.e. my constructor calling syntax now is "temp[cPop++] = new chromo_typ(offspring1, 0.0f);" but I am getting this error now "'VM_Placement.Program.chromo_typ' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments"

Comment: But I do have a constructor taking 2 arguments in my structure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, `chromo_typ` is a constructor, but you are calling it as an instance method.  Constructors are used to construct an object, i.e.,

```
temp[cPop++] = new chromo_typ(arg1, arg2);
```

It is not a method that you can call on an instance of your type.

On a side note, the canonical way to name types in C# is to use start with an uppercase letter and use camel case, i.e.,

```
public struct ChromoTyp { }
```

Of course, this is not a rule, but it is usually a good idea to follow the patterns already in use by the community.

Comment: Yes I know its a constructor, but so how do I make a call to that constructor? I need to create the structure object right?

Comment: @user1277070: I gave you an example.  You must use the `new` keyword.

Comment: Hey I tried using 'new' keyword as the same way in your example... but now I am getting this error: "VM_Placement.Program.chromo_typ' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments"

Comment: My syntax is "temp[cPop++] = new chromo_typ(offspring1, 0.0f);"

Comment: Could it be because I am assigning it to an array of chromo_typ i.e. temp[cPop++] is of type chromo_typ "chromo_typ[] temp = new chromo_typ[VM_Placement.AlgorithmParameters.pop_size];" ??

Comment: @EdS. it looks like his constructor is private, no?

Comment: @climbage - I made the constructor public and the error went off... but by default everything in a structure is public right?

Comment: @user1277070 in C++ maybe--C# is going to be a little different

Comment: @user1277070 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479214/any-reason-to-write-the-private-keyword-in-c for more info on default visibility

Comment: yes in C++ it is... so I thought it would be same for C# as well... anyways Thank you all for instant help... I appreciate it!!

Comment: @climbage: So it is, I missed that.