# Generating explicit private and internal modifiers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I started my C# journey few months ago with a beginning of a project. Unfortunately, back then I didn't mind implicit `private` and `internal`. Now I would like to somehow generate them. I've searched through Visual Studio's and ReSharper's possibilities, no results. My code is pretty large now and I would hate editting it manually.

Is there any option to solve that?

Comment: Why? Is it all public now, and you want to restrict access? Is it a large project?

Comment: No, it is private or internal by default, but I would prefer them to be explicitly stated (reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8479246/2946480).

I also make an editor (the program is a game, actually) and it would facilitate conversion of some parts to public (so I can edit them)

Comment: When everything else fails, find and replace with regular expressions can be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in Resharper with: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and choose full cleanup ([more info](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html))

Be sure you you has the following Resharper options checked:

- Pull down menu: Resharper / Options.
- Code editing / C# / other
- Check all boxes under Modifiers.